# CSS border issues when using :hover on the tr

Tags: css

I'm trying to highlight the row the mouse is over in a table of data. I'm trying to do this with a border-top and border-bottom. To help the readability i also have a light transparent png on alternate rows.

It seems that when I turn on and off the borders (works in IE8+ and FF) the rows jump around a little. I think I can fix it by having a a non-hover transparent border, rather than none at all. Is this x-browser compatible now days?

In Chrome, the highlighted row's border does not go away when you move the mouse off the row, why?

http://justinzaun.com/Tree/people/

**Update:** I've fixed the border issue in chrome where they wouldn't go away. I moved the border to the TDs rather than the TR. The rows are still jumping around though.

Thanks!

Comment: In Chrome (for me) the border goes away when I move down, but not when I move up the page.

Comment: @w3d - I've solved that issue, just the rows moving around issue left

Answer (score 34, accepted):

put an transparent border on your normal state elements.

When the `:hover` is applied the size of the border changes the size the element takes up.

eg:

```
.myelement
{
        border:4px solid transparent;
}

.myelement:hover
{
    border: 4px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPmRA/

**EDIT:-** more specifically to your table *(ugh: tables ... collapse border makes the above not work properly)*

http://jsfiddle.net/mPmRA/1/

put the transperant border on the `tr`

```
tr
{
    border-top:4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
}
```

And for the hover do something like:

```
tr:hover td
{
    border-top:4px solid green;
    border-bottom:4px solid green;
}
```

The `td` borders will then appear ABOVE the row's border.

Comment: I try to avoid commenting old posts, but seeing how I already have the "Necromancer Badge" here goes: James, this nearly 8 year old answer is still solving problems in 2019.The use of `border-collapse: collapse;` on tables is almost a given these days, and your edit providing `tr:hover td` is **gold**. The use of `:state` feels like it should be the **end** of a selector; adding more detail _after_ `:state` is not default thinking IMO. Its brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Make sure to have the same border-style in the definitions, i.e. "solid" in this case. Careless mixing of solid and dashed didn't work for me in Chromium.

Comment: 2022 and it's still a relevant solution.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way is adding "margin-top:-1px; margin-bottom: -1px;" to the :hover style, this corrects the new height with the border.

Comment: Hi Wulf, I've update the css to include the negative margins, the rows are still jumping around though.

Comment: Or, may be add padding to the default style and take it away on the `:hover` style when you add the borders?

Comment: +1 Great call, this is better than trying to support IE8 transparency when dealing with hover menus that add borders

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your border is set to the INSIDE instead of the outside. Unfortunetly, the inset option for borders is not yet part of CSS. Here's a bit of CSS to make the borders inside the element using box shadows:

```
.mytable tr:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

That will make a 1px black border on the INSIDE of your element! :D
I hope this helps, if you're set on a black dotted border, your only option is to set absolute positioning, and position each table row individually, which is a pain in the ass. :/
If you've got relative or static positioning, elements will move when other increase in size. Wulf's idea may work with a little configuring, but to be honest, the box shadow is a much nicer border then the dotted one. (a bit tacky if I say so myself. ^_^ Sorry.)