# Add border when hover over a cell in bootstrap table with table-border

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

i have a table like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/nmw82od1/
And i have this css:

```css
.table1 td:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table2 td:hover {
  border: 1px double black;
}
```

I want a border in every td, when i hover a td.
If i use double, it works in all other cells, than the row in the top.

Anyone got a good solution to get border work as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS border issues when using :hover on the tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834920/css-border-issues-when-using-hover-on-the-tr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you face is due to `display` property `table-cell` which is added by bootstrap. to resolve, use `display:block`. Working **snippet** below:

**UPDATE**: minor padding added to resolve the jumping effect...

```css
.table1 td:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 11px 11px;
  display: block;
}

.table2 td:hover {
  border: 1px double black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <table class="table1 table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Donald</td>
        <td>Duck</td>
        <td>donald@duck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Daisy</td>
        <td>Duck</td>
        <td>daisy@duck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Scrooge</td>
        <td>McDuck</td>
        <td>scrooge@mcduck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Gladstone</td>
        <td>Gander</td>
        <td>gladstone@gander.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <table class="table2 table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Donald</td>
        <td>Duck</td>
        <td>donald@duck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Daisy</td>
        <td>Duck</td>
        <td>daisy@duck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Scrooge</td>
        <td>McDuck</td>
        <td>scrooge@mcduck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Gladstone</td>
        <td>Gander</td>
        <td>gladstone@gander.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Akber, it is closer to a solution than my solutions. But your solution makes the text inside the tds jump, when hover the cells.

Comment: @jakobdo, minor padding work to mimic the pre-hover state